How to replace dresser drawer bottoms
I have a cheap dresser (probably IKEA) that I got second hand. It has a thin wood/ cardboard board at the bottom of it. Over time a few of the drawer bottoms have warped and fallen out of place as a result.
How do I replace or fix them?

Replace - what is the drawer bottom called so I can Google how to replace it
FIX - Are there any simple solutions to unwarp and keep them in place?

EDIT: The issue looks like this:


Can you take a drawer out, turn it upside down, and take a picture showing the bottom and the back of the drawer?  It will help us see how the bottom is held in.

Ikea is disposable/temporary, not really designed to be repaired. You may be able to get replacement drawers or parts from them.

I would consider replacing the bottoms with new panel, but there's not enough information here to help. The question assumes familiarity with IKEA construction and that all such furniture is similar. Please revise to be more clear.

That's better, but we still can't see the construction of the drawer from that angle and photo size. Please post a larger view of the underside, as you see in Huesmann's answer. This is basic communication, not some mysterious protocol. It may be clear to you, but you're standing there looking at it.

This is typical of flat pack furniture—the drawer bottoms are just too thin to hold too much weight, and simply bend/warp over time.
The bottom panel can be put back in place and once straightened should stay in place.  Depending how close the bottom piece is to the bottom of the drawer box, you can add a reinforcement bar or two—either below the panel or on top.  Think something like a 1x2 piece of lumber, cut to fit inside the drawer box.  Use glue and some short screws to screw through the panel into the bar.  The bar should keep the panel straighter, and keep it from falling out of the slots in the drawer box.
Edit:
Adding a couple of pics to kinda show what I mean.
This pic shows the bottom of the drawer.  In my case the drawer has a slot that tracks a rail in the cabinet box; the piece with the slot had cracked and I had to replace it.  In this drawer, the bottom panel was also too small to reach the slots in all the sides, so it wouldn't stay in place consistently.  You can see where I put in some screws into the side panel, sticking out to keep the bottom panel from falling out.

Here you can see the screws I put through the bottom panel to fasten it to the track bar beneath.  With this bar secured to it, the bottom panel won't flex enough with the weight of its contents to work its way out of the front and rear slots.


Thanks, do you have any specific kits or tutorials on this that you recommend?

@Moish I added a couple of pics to hopefully kinda show what I mean.
